# How can I deploy Symmetricds as a Web Archive (WAR) on my windows hosting (Plesk)

Tags: database, replication, database-replication, symmetricds

I'm trying to sync a cloud database (Windows hosting) with local database using `Symmetricds`, I succeeded to sync two database on my local network, But I failed to deploy `Symmetricds` on my windows hosting to configure cloud database as Master database.

How can I deploy Symmetricds as a Web Archive (WAR) on my windows hosting?

Comment: What server container/application server are you going to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the documentation on how to deploy a WAR file for SymmetricDS.

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.14/html/user-guide.html#_web_archive_war

Without knowing the errors that you are running into, we are unable to provide any further help with this issue.